# Snake decoration does not work with decorations.pathmorphing in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I have simple example that works fine

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]   
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1pt]               
            \draw[fill = black!100] {[snake] (0, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (2, 0)circle[radius=2pt]} -- (7, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (9, 0)circle[radius=2pt];             
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{time-line.}
        \label{fig:cus}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I noticed in output that :

```
Package tikz Warning: Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Please use th
e decoration libraries instead of the snakes library on input line 14.
```

If I change my code to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]   
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1pt]               
            \draw[fill = black!100] {[decorate,decoration=snake] (0, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (2, 0)circle[radius=2pt]} -- (7, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (9, 0)circle[radius=2pt];             
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{time-line.}
        \label{fig:cus}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

it does not draw the "snake" as in the first example. How to replace snakes library for tikz package with decorations correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not know about this feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]   
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1pt]               
\draw[fill = black!100] circle[radius=2pt] decorate [decoration={snake}]
 {(0, 0) -- (2, 0)} circle[radius=2pt] -- (7, 0) circle[radius=2pt] -- (9, 0) circle[radius=2pt];             
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{time-line.}
\label{fig:cus}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A good answer. Just a detail: in this example the `(0,0)` coordinates (a _moveto_ operation) are useless.

Comment: As "H" option used with figure environment, one needs to load the `float' package too!